# Proving that the exponential satisfies the following sum equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, exponential-function

I was thinking about how $(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!})^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}
$

and was wondering if there existed any other sequences that satisfied this besides the exponential. My gut instinct tells me no, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

$(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n)^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n a_n
$

I managed to show $a_{n+1} < \frac{a_n}{x}$ as $n \to \infty$ for any positive $x$, but I have absolutely no idea how to go any further.

Comment: I think it can be shown that $a_n$ must be of the form $a_n = y^n/n!$, where $y$ can be any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We consider a function $f$ defined on a subset $X$ of the real numbers.
\begin{align*}
&f:X\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{+}\\
&f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n
\end{align*}
The functional relation we are looking for can then be written as
\begin{align*}
\left(f(1)\right)^x=f(x)
\end{align*}
or equivalently
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{e^{x\cdot\ln f(1)}=f(x)}
\end{align*}
Setting $y:=\ln f(1)=\mathrm{const.}$ the function $f$ has the form
\begin{align*}
f(x)=e^{xy}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(xy)^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
in accordance with a comment from @JohnBarber.

Answer (score 0):

For equation

$$
(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n)^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n a_n
$$

Assume there exist b, such that

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^na_i = b 
$$

Otherwise, the equation has no significance.

Then we have

$$
b^x=e^{x\ln b}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n(\ln b)^n}{n!}
$$

Therefore

$$
a_n =\frac{\ln^n b}{n!}
$$

Notice that all above bases on that $\sum_{n}^{\infty} a_n$ converges to b.

Comment: I think you just showed that both sequences must converge to the same value. I don’t think that necessitates the equality of coefficients.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Oh, I got you, I'm wrong, :(